# Splitting string with Space as a delimiter

Tags: c#

Why is the below code not valid to split strings to find the number of words?
valueAsString is a string with a valid value;

```
valuesAsString.Split(" ");
```

The below code works fine

```
valuesAsString.Split(' ');
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What did you mean "not valid"? You mean there's a compilation error? Which error?

Comment: Because there's no such overload. Why no such overload? Guess only the programmers working for Microsoft who write the framework can say for sure otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overloads for `string.Split` are:

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
public string[] Split(params char[] separator, int count) 
public string[] Split(params char[] separator, StringSplitOptions options) 
public string[] Split(params char[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options) 
public string[] Split(string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options) 
public string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options)
```

so `string.Split(char)` works because the `params` specifier allows the compiler to treat a single character as an array with one value, so the first overload is chosen.

Since

```
public string[] Split(params string[] separator)
```

and

```
public string[] Split(string separator)
```

are not overloads, and there is no implicit conversion from a `string` to a `char[]`, the compiler cannon directly bind `string.Split(string)`.

Some alternatives that would work:

```
valuesAsString.Split(new [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
valuesAsString.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
```

or just

```
valuesAsString.Split();
```

since the compiler treats the lack of values as an empty "array" for the `params` parameter, and per the documentation:

> If the separator parameter is null or contains no characters, white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard and return true if they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method.

Comment: +1 for `ToCharArray()`, nice trick!

Answer (score 1):

Because the Split function take a `char` or a `char[]` as an argument, see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx for quote operators.

Answer (score 1):

Split needs a char as a delimiter. When you use double quotes your are marking it as a string. If you use single quotes it's a char.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Split method with one parameter expect a char parameter (or an array of char) : look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Not really, it has several overloads including array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloaded version I think:

```
valuesAsString.Split(new [] { " " } ,StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because String.Split needs a Char and not a String. ' ' stands for a Char, while " " stands for a  String